# Please tell me how to find the xpath for this script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="icheckbox-radio">
<div class="iradio_square-blue checked">
<input id="input-22" type="radio" value="OnDate" data-bind="CustomRadioBox:{checked:expiryType}" name="endradio" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"/>
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"/>
</div>
```

Please tell how to get the xpath for this element .This is a radio button when i have used these xpath but not able to clickable the radio button.
1.id.driver.findElement(By.id("input-22")).click();
2//input[@data-bind='CustomRadioBox:{checked:expiryType}' and @value='OnDate']

I have put the code in try catch block also.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IznIf.png)

Comment: Why can't use name? Or build xapth with name

Comment: Tell us the error when you try to click using id but fails

Answer (score 0):

Please try to locate the element with JavaScript executor

```
WebElement OPtionButton= driver.findElement(By.id("input-22"));
JavascriptExecutor ExeCute = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
ExeCute.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", OPtionButton);
```